# How to search in all files in a directory and subdirectory using grep

Tags: linux

I have to search a string. I have one directory having lot of files and other subdirectories as well.

How can i solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `grep -rin "string" *`

where r is for recursive, n gives line number and i to ingnore case 
and * for all files

Answer (score 1):

`grep -r <your_string> .`

`-r` flag lets you do that recursively